# Incompatible pointer type warning in os161

Tags: c, operating-system, os161

I am implementing a fork system call in os161 kernel. I am trying to create a new process and for its thread creation I used `thread_fork`. I am using the function `md_forkentry` to allocate heap and stack to the trapframe of the new thread and switch to user mode; but I get this warning after compiling the code:
`passing arg 4 of 'thread_fork' from incompatible pointer type`

```
//Function Prototypes
int thread_fork(const char* name,void* data1,unsgined long data2,void (*func) (void*,unsigned long),struct thread **ret)
void md_forkentry(struct trapframe* tf,unsigned long n);

//the code 
struct trapframe* tf;
struct thread* child_thread;
//line I get the error from
int result=thread_fork("Child Process",(void*) tf,0,&md_forkentry,&child_thread);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prototype for `md_forkentry()` does not match the type of the 4th parameter of `thread_fork()`.

`md_forkentry()` must be prototyped as:

```
void md_forkentry(void *, unsigned long);
```

(or vice-versa, i.e. fix the parameter type given in the prototype for `thread_fork()` if necessary)